# Нужно ли пояснять значения терминов в вопросах?

Tags: обсуждение, закрытие-вопросов, причины-закрытия, вопрос-аккордеон

На основе обсуждений у вопроса [Как сделать аккордеон?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/468108/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%BD)

Если спросить, как реализовать синглтон, то ведь не надо в вопросе копипастить или пересказывать определение синглтона. Так почему же надо пояснять, что такое *аккордеон*?

Собственно, моё мнение на эту тему выражено в девятой [правке](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/468108/revisions), правда, в десятой этот кусок удалили как "эмоциональную отсебятину".

> *Дополнение по пожеланиями десятерых закрывателей вопроса:*
>
> Для тех, кто не знает (хм.. а чего тогда в этот вопрос забрели?), аккордеон - это набор сворачиваемых блоков, среди которых одновременно только один (или не более одного) может быть в развёрнутом состоянии.

Все, кто зашёл в вопрос либо знают, что такое аккордеон, поскольку ищут как его сделать, либо могут ответить и просто знают, что это такое. А если не знают, то им просто надо пройти мимо. Вот например в вопросе [Как сделать Get-запрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/123295/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-get-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81) ведь никто не требует пояснения, что такое get-запрос. Почему-то никто из незнающих, что такое get-запрос, не пытается закрыть.

**Так почему же в других случаях надо действовать по принципу

*"Я закрываю этот вопрос, поскольку его не понимаю"***

Comment: Я не закрыватель :-), но ища открывающиеся панели - можно даже не подумать что они называются аккордеоном, если до этого не сталкивался с этим.

Comment: вполне известное определение. [1](https://jqueryui.com/accordion/), [2](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/javascript.html#collapse), ну и не мало важно наличие одноимённой метки на SO: [accordion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/accordion)

Comment: @AlexanderIgorevich, по ссылке на бутстрап - все-таки `Collapse` и аккордеон только внутри

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По-моему все просто.

*"Можно ли этот код заккордеонить?"* - плохое название, потому что глагол *"зааккордеонить"* применительно к существительному "код" может вызывать недопонимание. *"заакордеонить список"* было бы еще терпимо.

Нынешнее *"Как сделать аккордеон?"* вполне понятно. Кто не знает про аккордеон, может спросить в комментарии.

**Вывод**: нужно в первую очередь писать качественные вопросы и заголовки. Пояснять значения терминов - по требованию.

---

Раз вы взяли под опеку этот вопрос, пример с codepen стоит перенести в сниппет.

Comment: Замечу, что второй раз вопрос был закрыт уже с заголовком "Как сделать аккордеон?"

Answer (score 3):

Как я вижу этот вопрос:

было

> Subj: я тут написал портянку кода, не работает. Поработайте за меня!:
>
> ссылка на портянку кода

стало

> Subj: я тут написал портянку кода, не работает:
>
> ```
> Портянка кода, которую надо отладить, чтобы понять, что именно не работает, 
> потому что топикастер поленился минимизировать пример 
> и даже не вырезал совершенно не имеющую отношения к вопросу рыбу
> <a href="">dsa</a><a href="">gedgs</a><a href="">sdgbdsgb</a><a href="">sdvgdsv</a>
> <a href="">dsa</a><a href="">gedgs</a><a href="">sdgbdsgb</a><a href="">sdvgdsv</a>
> <a href="">dsa</a><a href="">gedgs</a><a href="">sdgbdsgb</a><a href="">sdvgdsv</a>
> <a href="">dsa</a><a href="">gedgs</a><a href="">sdgbdsgb</a><a href="">sdvgdsv</a>
> <a href="">dsa</a><a href="">gedgs</a><a href="">sdgbdsgb</a><a href="">sdvgdsv</a>
> ```

Да, проблема, очевидно, была в заголовке!

Уточнять термины в заголовке не имеет большого смысла, если весь вопрос требует уточнения и переработки.

Comment: `[:|||:]` `[:|||||||:]` `[:|||:]` `[:|||||||:]`

Answer (score 0):

**По-существу вопроса, отраженного в заголовке:**

Пояснять значения терминов в самом вопросе имеет смысл только тогда, когда эти термины не понятны окружающим. Обычно, факт "непонятности" становится очевиден из комментариев к вопросу.

---

**По вопросу** [Как сделать аккордеон?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/468108/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%BD)

Проблема данного конкретного вопроса вовсе не в кривом заголовке с непонятным термином. Безусловно, этот термин стоило бы расшифровать, но это не принципиально (среди нас есть же телепаты, верно?).

Основная проблема этого вопроса в другом: он сводится к "*Вот портянка кода, как сделать аккордеон (чтобы работало)?*". Именно поэтому этот вопрос плох.

В описании к стрелочке вниз есть такие слова:

> Данный вопрос не отражает стремления разобраться; он не понятен или не несет пользы.

Руководствуясь этим комментарием, вопрос заслуживает "минус". Как он набрал пять плюсов лично мне не понятно.

На мой взгляд, вопрос так же попадает под закрытие из за своей неконкретности. Сами подумайте: автор приводит код какой-то и говорит: "*а сделайте ка мне аккордеон*". Все. Ноль конкретики. Я именно по этому его закрывал, и закрыл бы снова, если бы система позволяла дважды закрывать один и тот же вопрос.

А кривой заголовок с непонятным термином это всего лишь вишенка на торте. Не надо раздувать проблему и высказываться в ключе "**вы закрываете только потому, что не понимаете**". Это не конструктивно!

Кстати "эмоциональную отсебятину" удалил тоже я ;) Но драматизировать не надо: был удален не весь кусок с объяснением термина, а только та язвительная часть, которая содержала эмоциональный окрас. Коллеги, мы же профессионалы. Вопрос в IT это четко сформулированная проблема, а не место для выплескивания своих эмоций.

Comment: "был удален не весь кусок с объяснением термина" - ну так я именно весь кусок считаю лишним, а удалено было моё мнение по поводу этого куска, что я и сказал.

Comment: "автор приводит код какой-то и говорит: "а сделайте ка мне аккордеон"." - не какой-то код, а код разворачивания блока. Для аккордеона не хватает кода сворачивания. Поэтому вопрос и нормальный.

Comment: @Qwertiy, это был бы код разворачивания блока если бы автор удосужился прокомментировать, что именно он делал и что не получилось. А в текущем виде это именно "какой-то код". Я даже за попытку решения не стал бы его рассматривать.

Comment: @Qwertiy, лично у меня нет желания вникать в некий, код, угадывать что он делает, пытаться понять где ошибка и выполнять задачу за автора полностью. Вы посмотрите на оригинальный вопрос: там нет **ни одного слова** о проблеме кроме кривого заголовка. В данном случае подходит формулировка закрытия "_Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой_"

Answer (score 0):

На мой взгляд все три предыдущих ответа, включая принятый, неправильные.
Чтобы не приходилось каждый раз пересказывать все определения, на stackexchange используются метки.
На ruSO метки для синглтона нет, а вот на enSO по этой метке [находится](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/singleton) 5k+ вопросов. И метка [accordion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/accordion) там тоже есть, по ней 2k+ вопросов.
По метке GET ситуация немного другая - на ruSO она [есть](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/get) (100+ вопросов), но в упомянутом Вами сообщении её не догадались поставить.

[Что такое метки и как их использовать](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/tagging)

Comment: В вопросе может быть не более 5 меток.

Answer (score -2):

А вот в вопросе [период дроби double](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/470449/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B8-double) вспыхнула жаркая дискуссия на тему совместимости понятия периода с конечостью представления данных. Хотя суть проблемы - не в схоластических упражнениях, а в уточнении и правильной формулировке вопроса.
Теперь жду, будет ли принята правка вопроса участниками дискуссии.

Comment: Кажется, тебе куда-то туда: http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1840/178988

Comment: Спасибо, правку приняли. Но у возникшей ситуации была своя причина, и она - здесь.

Comment: @YuriNegometyanov суть проблемы в том, что double - это конкретный тип данных. "в два раза точнее обычного флоата". как не формулируй -  вопрос смысла не несет.

Comment: @YuriNegometyanov и да, ваш ответ там - ужасен и в корне неверен.

Comment: @YuriNegometyanov и это дубль http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/470322/ и тем не менее, вы пытаетесь его "улучшить и переоткрыть".

Comment: @PashaPash После моей правки - уже нет. А "Дилемма о double" того же автора - стала просто конфетой. Просто надо сбросить личные настройки и прочитать, что там написано.

Comment: Он как был дублем так и остался. Ваша правка этого никак не исправляет. Ну да, вы подогнали формулировку под свой ответ. Дубликатом он от этого быть не перестал.

Comment: Более того, ответ на него в такой формулировке - "нет, нельзя".

Comment: По поводу дубля - согласен. Понимаю, что изначально так и было. Но где вы все были с этой ссылкой, когда шли схоластические рассуждения? А теперь дело сделано, автора устроил ответ..

Comment: @PashaPash Теперь даже интересно, какое отношение будет к "Дилемме".  :)

Comment: @YuriNegometyanov в каком смысле "где я был со ссылкой?". Вы же знали про существование обоих вопросов :). А то, что автора устроил ответ - ещё не означает что ответ хороший или правильный. И тем более - это не даёт вам повода подставлять вопрос так, чтобы ваш ответ стал " правильнее" остальных

Comment: PashaPash Мои приоритетные метки - алгоритмы, математика, битовые операции и и PHP (выборочно). Случилось так, что я реально пропустил ту тему и не понял, за что автора так отчаянно минусят. Сразу после исправления ответа я оставил автору сообщение, чтобы он яснее формулировал мысль. Но больше его ответов в теме не было. Поэтому идея, чтобы автор сделал это сам, не кажется мне удачной. Потому что люди будут видеть одно, а читать про другое. Я бы приветствовал попытки любого другого участника СО как-то смягчить этот диссонанс. Поскольку в настоящий момент мои правки ликвидированы.